# Fast algorithm for cumulative intersection of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, intersection

I want to calculate the cumulative intersection of two arrays. For example

```
> cumulative_intersection([1,3,4,5,2,6], [4,1,5,2,3,7])
[[], [1], [1,4], [1,4,5], [1,4,5,3,2], [1,4,5,3,2]]
```

I can brute-force implement this using a loop. For example, in Python,

```
a1 = [1,3,4,5,2,6]
a2 = [4,1,5,2,3,7]
n = len(a1)
all_intersects = list()
for i in range(n):
    intersect = np.intersect1d(a1[:i], a2[:i])
    all_intersects.append(intersect)
```

Is there a more efficient algorithm to compute this? My intuition is that computation can be reduced logarithmically, because each successive list is a superset of the previous one.

Comment: Do the arrays contain unique integers?

Comment: ```np.intersect1d()``` will return sorted array, so the ouput will become ```[[], [1], [1,4], [1,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]```

Comment: as pointed out by hsin.att214, is the order of each array in output important (do they have to be sorted by first number found in intersection ?). How big are your arrays? If order does not matter I'd consider sorting both array and iterate with one for oop, if order matters, I'd do the same but consider integer + their original position, and sort again the resulting array according to the max of their original position. this way you compute intersection only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your intersection algorithm with one that doesn't sort the result (and thus takes linear time), your brute force algorithm's asymptotic complexity becomes O(n<sup>2</sup>) which is already at your problem's lower bound asymptotic complexity.

To demonstrate this lower bound, let's assume for the sake of argument, that you have an O(1) method for determining what numbers needed to be added to the ith intersection to get the (i+1)th intersection. Therefore, if C(i) is the time to copy the ith intersection, your total runtime would be

[image: O(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[ C(i-1) + O(1)\right] = O(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}C(i-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}O(1)]

Now then, copying an array is an O(n) operation, and in the worst case where your two arrays are the same, the ith intersection has length i+1. Therefore, your worse case run-time is

[image: O(1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}O(i-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}O(1) = O(n^2) + O(n) =O(n^2)]

That being said, you can beat your naive algorithm's run-time by a constant factor by modifying the O(n) greedy algorithm for generating the intersection of two lists.

```
def intersection(a: list,b: list):
    ''' Computes the interection of lists a and b. Assumes that a and b have the same 
    length'''
    a_leftover = set()
    b_leftover = set()
    stored = set() # We only want unique values
    n = len(a)
    result = []
    for i in range(n):
        a_elm = a[i]
        b_elm = b[i]
        if a_elm not in stored and a_elm == b_elm:
            result.append(a_elm)
            stored.add(a_elm)
        else:
            if a_elm not in stored:
                if a_elm in b_leftover:
                    # a_elm was previously encountered in b
                    result.append(a_elm)
                    stored.add(a_elm)
                    b_leftover.remove(a_elm)
                else:
                    a_leftover.add(a_elm)
            if b_elm not in stored:
                if b_elm in a_leftover:
                    # b_elf was previously encountered in a
                    result.append(b_elm)
                    stored.add(b_elm)
                    a_leftover.remove(b_elm)
                else:
                    b_leftover.add(b_elm)
    return result
```

All you would need to do is modify the algorithm to store and return the intermediate results.

```
def cumulative_intersection(a: list,b: list):
    ''' Computes the cumulative interection of lists a and b. Assumes that a and b have the same 
    length'''
    a_leftover = set()
    b_leftover = set()
    stored = set() # We only want unique values
    n = len(a)
    result = []
    results = []
    for i in range(n):
        a_elm = a[i]
        b_elm = b[i]
        if a_elm not in stored and a_elm == b_elm:
            result.append(a_elm)
            stored.add(a_elm)
        else:
            if a_elm not in stored:
                if a_elm in b_leftover:
                    # a_elm was previously encountered in b
                    result.append(a_elm)
                    stored.add(a_elm)
                    b_leftover.remove(a_elm)
                else:
                    a_leftover.add(a_elm)
            if b_elm not in stored:
                if b_elm in a_leftover:
                    # b_elf was previously encountered in a
                    result.append(b_elm)
                    stored.add(b_elm)
                    a_leftover.remove(b_elm)
                else:
                    b_leftover.add(b_elm)
        results.append(result[:])
    return results
```

Comment: ```np.intersect1d``` does not take linear time as it concats the arrays and sorts the concated array.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware that it sorts the array. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
a1 = [1,3,4,5,2,6]
a2 = [4,1,5,2,3,7]
n = len(a1)
all_intersects = list()
current_intersect = list()
s1 = set()
s2 = set()
for i in range(n):
   if a2[i] not in s2 and a2[i] in s1:
      current_intersect.append(a2[i])
   if a1[i] not in s1 and a1[i] in s2:
      current_intersect.append(a1[i])
   all_intersects.append(list(current_intersect))
   s1.add(a1[i])
   s2.add(a2[i])
```

The general idea is to keep two sets of numbers that have been seen. Set `s1` keeps track of numbers that have been seen in list `a1`. Set `s2` keeps track of numbers that have been seen in list `a2`.

When processing a number from list `a1`, if the number hasn't been seen yet, but has been seen in the list `a2`, then we can add it to the list of numbers in `current_intersect`. Likewise for the number from list `a2`.

After updating `current_intersect`, the `current_intersect` is added to `all_intersects`. Also, the current array elements are added to the two sets.

Comment: I ran this and the other answer, and both worked. They had nearly identical runtimes on my computer as well. Since the other answer was posted first, I opted to mark it as "best," but thank you very much for this concise solution